# How to convert an Javascript Array to an HTML Span?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

I have an array of objects like this

```
var data = [{
        "name": "Lichtbediening",
        "category": "category",
        "info": "Klik voor lichtbediening",
        "img": "lichtbediening"
}, {
        "name": "Stopcontact",
        "category": "category",
        "info": "Klik voor stopcontacten",
        "img": "stopcontacten"
}, {
        "category": "Lichtbediening",
        "name": "Enkele schakelaar",
        "info": "Een knop, een lamp",
        "img": "rolluikbediening"       
}, {
        "category": "Stopcontact",
        "name": "Enkel stopcontact",
        "info": "Twee knoppen, twee lampen",
        "img": "multimedia"     
}];
```

Is there a way so that I can convert it to span tags with different ids like:

```
<span id="element1">
    name="Lichtbediening"
    category="category"
    info="Klik voor lichtbediening"
    img="lichtbediening"></span>
```

And similarly other elements in array as well.

Thanks

Comment: Like each element in array converted to <span id="element1"
        "name": "Lichtbediening",
        "category": "category",
        "info": "Klik voor lichtbediening",
        "img": "lichtbediening"
</span>

Comment: Sure there is but Stackoverflow is not a *"how to"* tutorial service. You should be able to find lots of resources on web to explain how

Comment: http://jsbin.com/juhinihule/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the object array indexes as id suffix. And then create a  tag and for each member of the object, create an attribute. Like this:

```js
var data = [{
  "name": "Lichtbediening",
  "category": "category",
  "info": "Klik voor lichtbediening",
  "img": "lichtbediening"
}, {
  "name": "Stopcontact",
  "category": "category",
  "info": "Klik voor stopcontacten",
  "img": "stopcontacten"
}, {
  "category": "Lichtbediening",
  "name": "Enkele schakelaar",
  "info": "Een knop, een lamp",
  "img": "rolluikbediening"
}, {
  "category": "Stopcontact",
  "name": "Enkel stopcontact",
  "info": "Twee knoppen, twee lampen",
  "img": "multimedia"
}];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.id = "element" + i;
  var content = "";
  for (var a in data[i])
    content += " " + a + "='" + data[i][a] + "'";
  span.innerHTML = content;
  console.log(span);
  document.body.appendChild(span);
}
```

Comment: can the downvoters explain why?

Comment: Thanks for quick response .. Please can you suggest a jquery method so  that I can take the id (like id = element0) and display first array elements on a button click.  Thanks again

Comment: @Nicole please search for an existing answer to your second question or create a new question for it if there isn't one already.

Comment: @BillyBrown is right. That deserves another question to be asked.

Comment: THanks.. Is there a way to get array elements in the body of span tag like<span id="element1">
    name="Lichtbediening"
    category="category"
    info="Klik voor lichtbediening"
    img="lichtbediening"  </span>                                                                                             Not to set them as attributes

Comment: Ok, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Updated my answer for the latest comment of yours.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
var items = data.map(function (item, i) {
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  for (var x in item) {
    span.setAttribute(x, item[x]);
  }

  span.setAttribute('id', 'element'+(i+1));

  return span;
});
```

Now `items` contains four **span** elements which can be appended to the document

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that converts a single object from your array into a `span` element:

```
function itemToSpan(item, index) {
    let span = document.createElement('span');
    span.id = 'element' + (index + 1);
    for (const field : item) {
        span.setAttribute(field, item[field]);
    }
    return span;
}
```

You can then convert the items to spans with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
let spans = data.map(itemToSpan);
```

If you then want to add them all to the document, you can use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
spans.forEach(document.body.appendChild);
```

So combined that makes:

```
data.map(itemToSpan).forEach(document.body.appendChild);
```

EDIT for answering final comment:

```
function itemToSpan(item, index) {
    let span = document.createElement('span');
    span.id = 'element' + (index + 1);
    // Iterate over each field in the object
    for (const field : item) {
        span.innerText += field + '="' + item[field] + '" ';
    }
    // Strip the trailing space
    span.innerText = span.innerText.trim();
    return span;
}
```

Comment: thanks .. can we get span like <span id="element1"> name="Lichtbediening" category="category" info="Klik voor lichtbediening" img="lichtbediening" </span>   where name , category, etc are actually body of span , not set as attributes

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    //create a span element for each data object in the array
    var span = document.createElement("span");

    //set the id, name, category, img and info attributes of each 
    object in the array
    span.setAttribute("id", "element" + i);
    span.setAttribute("name", data[i].name);
    span.setAttribute("category", data[i].category);
    span.setAttribute("info", data[i].info);
    span.setAttribute("img", data[i].info);

    //append each span element to the body of the html
    document.body.appendChild(span);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. Your code is not HTML tho because of non-standard attributes, you can use data-atribute-name to make it HTML.

```
   var data = [{
            "name": "Lichtbediening",
            "category": "category",
            "info": "Klik voor lichtbediening",
            "img": "lichtbediening"
    }, {
            "name": "Stopcontact",
            "category": "category",
            "info": "Klik voor stopcontacten",
            "img": "stopcontacten"
    }, {
            "category": "Lichtbediening",
            "name": "Enkele schakelaar",
            "info": "Een knop, een lamp",
            "img": "rolluikbediening"       
    }, {
            "category": "Stopcontact",
            "name": "Enkel stopcontact",
            "info": "Twee knoppen, twee lampen",
            "img": "multimedia"     
    }];

    data.forEach(function(element) {
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.setAttribute("id", "democlass");
        span.setAttribute("name", "democlass");
        span.setAttribute("category", "democlass");
        span.setAttribute("info", "democlass");
        span.setAttribute("img", "democlass");
        console.log(span);
        document.body.appendChild(span);
    })
```

Furthermore, you should insert something in those elements to make them visible. They are in the DOM, F12 to see it but nothing is displayed on the 1st glance.

Fiddle:

[working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pfzds3sx/)